# xor operation between chars

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, xor

I have the following piece of Java code and while debugging in Eclipse, Windows 7, the variable 'xoredChar'  shows no value at all, not null, not '', nothing.

```
char xoredChar = (char) (stringA.charAt(j)^stringB.charAt(j));
```

Why is that? I need to understand how can I do this xor operation between two characters in java. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the strings are equal you'll get back a `\0` which is not a printable character. Try something like this,

```
String stringA = "A";
String stringB = "A";
int j = 0;
char xoredChar = (char) (stringA.charAt(j) ^ stringB.charAt(j));
System.out.printf("'%c' = %d\n", xoredChar, (int) xoredChar);
```

Output is

```
' ' = 0
```

Comment: I've got the following printed in the command line after the sysout       : ' ' = 32

Comment: so why am i getting a space?

Comment: @jbendahan Because the result of XORing the two characters is mathematically 32 - or a space. 'A' ^ 'a' == 32 for example.

Comment: At least now I now what the value is. But for the next character the xor is giving me a number 1. I thought the binary result of the xor was another ascii code thus a new character. Am I wrong?

Comment: @jbendahan Not every distinct character is printable. An ASCII 1 is distinct from an ASCII 0 but neither is likely printable. What are you actually trying to solve? And how does working with the `char` primitive like this help?

Answer (score 0):

If `stringA` and `stringB` are identical, then the XOR operation will yield `xoredChar = 0`.

A 0 is probably showing in your IDE as nothing since 0 is used as a string terminator in most instances.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the other answers, xoring the same characters results in a `\0` value, which has no visual representation. Perhapse you are interested in a small application, which gives you and idea how XOR works on your strings:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "abcde";
        String b = a;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < b.length(); idx++) {
            System.out.printf("xoring <%s> [%s] with <%s> [%s]\n",
                    a.charAt(0), toBinaryString(a.charAt(0)),
                    b.charAt(idx), toBinaryString(b.charAt(idx)));
            int c = (a.charAt(0) ^ b.charAt(idx));
            System.out.printf("result is <%s> [%s]\n",
                    (char) c, toBinaryString(c));
        }
    }
}
```

Have fun!